# How do I record audio in Javascript and upload to SoundCloud without using the User Connect Flow?

Tags: soundcloud

```
def upload(request):
    import soundcloud

    # create client object with app and user credentials
    client = soundcloud.Client(client_id='YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
                               client_secret='YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
                               username='YOUR_USERNAME',
                               password='YOUR_PASSWORD')

    # upload audio file
    track = client.post('/tracks', track={
        'title': 'This is my sound',
        'asset_data': request.POST.get('sound_data')
    })

    # print track link
    print track.permalink_url

    return HttpResponse('Successfully uploaded')
```

I'm trying to use a python layer to store my credentials and upload sound data to SoundCloud, however, the examples assume that I have an mp3 or similar sound file, not a ByteArray (which the SoundCloud JS SDK builds).

Basically, I want people to come to a page, record audio and upload it to MY SoundCloud account. I believe the above could work if I got the formatting correct.

Comment: The Python SDK does assume that you are including the contents of a file-like object in the request body. If you're able to get the contents of the ByteArray to the server without any difficulty, you should be able to construct a binary buffer (maybe a StringIO) and use that instead.

Comment: @PaulOsman Any chance you could write up a working example? I'm having a really hard time getting this to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you figure this out can you please let me know?  Still waiting for sound cloud to allow the api to be used without being attached to a logged in sound cloud user.

Comment: You can use the API to read public information using only a CLIENT_ID which identifies your application. Is this not sufficient for the use case you're thinking of? What is it specifically that you'd like to do?

Comment: I would like to use the soundcloud recorder and upload sounds without having the user to login with a sound cloud account. I need all the sounds to be under my account or application account.

Comment: You can do that with the OAuth User Credentials Flow: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/#user-credentials  Does that do what you're looking for?

Comment: In a way i guess it does help. I was hoping to use this http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#methods to do the recording and then upload it. But I can't. It would be nice if you can use the recorder then upload it with the example you provided.